# Very high CPU usage by explorer.exe constantly (something to do with Windows.Storage.Search.dll)

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, windows-explorer, debug

The problem started a few days ago and now it gets high to sometimes 12% and some time to 45% CPU usage. It doesn't start immediately but after a little while if you terminate explorer.exe and start it again.

Here is the WPR recording of the event. I get similar output in process explorer too. I don't know to make sense of it. There is nothing that seems wrong in Windows Indexing either.

I sometimes see explorer.exe is trying to read everything in c:\Users\Username  (it's worth 125 GB) which is strange but high CPU usage still happens even without disk usage so I think they are separate issues.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Run Windows 10 Updates and before executing the updates. look at the results. In the last 7 days, Microsoft has issued an optional (not critical) update aimed at fixing this issue. Apply all the updates including optional and do the necessary restart

Comment: @John I just installed KB4535996 (released on 16th Feb). Still same issue.

Comment: Assuming Windows 10 Pro (not Enterprise), you may wish now to consider a Windows 10 Repair install. Make sure DropBox (if used) is stopped first. Run in place and try the option Keep Everything.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10j

Comment: @John I think it worked. After the last comment, I uninstalled Start 10 and also did a restart. So either the uninstallation of Start 10 or another restart after the update did the magic. I am monitoring the CPU usage for the next few hours to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Yorik I think it worked. I uninstalled Start 10 and also updated the Windows. I think one of these worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Yorik It was indeed Start 10. If you can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is Stardock Start10 which hooks into Explorer.

If possible, you might try disabling Start10 to see if the problem is resolved. There may be an interaction between Explorer and Start10 or it may be some other hooked application that is unaware of Start10 or is aware of Start10 functionality (e.g. DisplayFusion) but is exposing an issue.

I personally had an issue many moons ago with a Stardock product which worked fine except for a particular critical software package, and only then when trying to use PCL 5 printers.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has issued updates for this. Run Windows 10 Updates and before executing the updates. look at the results. In the last 7 days, Microsoft has issued an optional (not critical) update aimed at fixing this issue. Apply all the updates including optional and do the necessary restart.

This will likely fix your problem